# What would be the best way to implement a user selection between converting to Celsius or Fahrenheit?

Tags: c#, user-input

```
namespace TemperatureConverter
{
    class Program
{
    public static float celsius, fahrenheit;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Are you converting Celsius or Fahrenheit?: ");
        celsius = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

        fahrenheit = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;

        Console.WriteLine("The temperature in fahrenheit is " + fahrenheit);
    }

    static void ToFahrenheit()
    {

    }

    static void ToCelsius()
    {

    }
}
```

}

I am trying to implement a way the user can select to convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit after compilation.

Comment: Welcome. Please post your code here and what you have tried so future visitors can benefit from your provided example.

Comment: If you're asking which way is most convenient for the user, I suggest requiring the scale to be part of the input; e.g. `32F` or `-44C`.

Comment: @DourHighArch, but that's Farad and Coulomb. It took me quite a while to understand that it's supposed to mean °F and °C, so I guess that input format would confuse a fair bit of the world (as °F isn't exactly common in most places).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to convert to (F)ahrenheit or to (C)elsius? ");
ConsoleKeyInfo key;
do
{
    key = Console.ReadKey();
    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.F)
    {
        return ToFahrenheit(/* */);
    }
    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
    {
        return ToCeclsius(/* */);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Please press F or C to make your selection");
} while (true);
```